# Stop ProgressBar animation after Value = Maximum

Tags: wpf, animation, triggers

I have added an animation for progress bar.

I am trying to stop the animation after maximum fill (changes every time). I am generating the progress bar maximum value from code behind based on the number of files I need to process.

Following is the code snippet I have

```
<Trigger Property="Value" Value="10">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Animation" Value="Collapsed"/>

</Trigger>
```

Above trigger works when the maximum value for progressbar is 10, but my question is how to update this value to dynamically generated maximum value.

Could some one please help me out?

I really appreciate your time

Comment: tags aren't search criteria. Tags are for categorization. Only use a more specific tag if the issue is more related to the specific tag and not the general one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more complicated way of doing this (but also more reusable) would be to use a `DataTrigger` with a `MultiBinding` and a `IMultiValueConverter`:

```
public class EqualsConverver : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length < 1)
            return Binding.DoNothing;

        var obj = values[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (!obj.Equals(values[i]))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And then your trigger would look like:

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource equalsConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
            <Binding Path="Maximum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Animation" Value="Collapsed"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thank you, This is exactly What I need. I have created this converter and placed the xaml code in style.xaml. When I update the value of the progressbar, this data trigger is not firing. I placed a break point in converter code, but control never reached to that point. My progressbar is in usercontrol, do i need to do anything different in this scenario?

Comment: Do I need to call ImultiConverter everytime I change the value like InotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: No it should work automatically when the value of either property changes. I was assuming the trigger is in the ProgressBar's template. If that isn't the case, instead of using RelativeSource, you should use ElementName bindings.

Comment: I did ElementName binding, but the problem is ImultiValue Converter is firing only once i.e. for the first time with unset values. It is not firing when I update the progress bar value.

Comment: Thank you Abe for your help and time on this. I got it working without mentioning RelativeSource or ElementName, just <Binding Path="Value" /> works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the Trigger, and since you already have code behind, you can register for the animation's [completed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).